# Is it possible to leverage WPF property system in a server application?

Tags: c#, wpf

We have legacy code which consists of business objects with over a hundred properties and a couple of layers in hierarchy.
Our goal is to translate it into a C# server application which will be invoked with WCF. WPF property system however seems to be a good tool to employ because it is more efficient and some other bonus features like property inheritance which would be useful for our library.

However, I am not aware whether it would be feasible to use it in a non-WPF application. Could someone please tell if it would work, and if there are example projects of using in non-WPF applications?

Comment: Are you talking about DependencyProperties?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is heavily based on DependencyProperties, but DependencyProperties are not a WPF specific feature, you can easily use it by themselves.

The same you can say about INotifyPropertyChanged interface - it can be implemented and used outside of WPF.

Answer (score 1):

DependencyProperties support comes from the class DependencyObject, which sits in WindowsBase.dll

If you have no problem adding that reference, there's absolutely no problem in using this in a Server side solution.

Due note however that this means u must inherit your classes from DependencyObject, which might cause a problem - C# doesn't support multi-inheritance.

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, although is easier and lighter - is not going to give you anything other than Change Notification which isn't really much. The feature-set of DependecyProperties is way bigger (like you mentioned). Also, DependencyProperties work MUCH faster if you're using Binding, since it doesn't use reflection (while INPC does)

I don't know of any server-side solutions that tried your approach, but I really can't see why not if you indeed want the functionality that DPs exposes.

--- EDIT ---

DependecyObject inherits DispatcherObject, which makes it accessible only from the thread that created it and therefore multithreading these objects is going to be a PAIN. if you need multithreading then this is a big no-go.

Answer (score 1):

Feasible? Yes. Practical? Probably not.

Being a server application, you will almost certainly want to access your business objects from any thread. But dependency objects have thread affinity and must be accessed by the thread on which they were created, via their Dispatcher if necessary. And if you use the dispatcher, that means you will need to have something pumping its events.

And this assumes that your business objects have properties *that often take on a default value*. If you don't have "common defaults", the sparse storage algorithms won't help you save memory. The reason the sparse storage system works well in WPF is because controls have so many properties, many of which always have the same values.

Essentially, you'd probably be in for quite a bit of pain, and may not even reduce memory usage. It seems to me you'd be better off working around your issues in some other manner, or implementing your own free-threaded sparse storage mechanism if you validate that it will, in fact, reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Would it take that much work to emulate the use of dependency properties?

Without needing to support XAML, it should be easy enough.

However, I found it easier to make a default indexer and use a string for the index.

You only have to remember to include the [ ] in any parsed file.

It's a cheaper dynamic property system for sure.